# Erro ao acessar nó filho no Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera, estou tendo problemas para acessar o nó filho no Firebase, está me retornando esse erro, gostaria de saber o que deve ser modificado para rodar o app normalmente, acima está meu código que já tentei rodar.

Segue minha estrutura no banco que quero acessar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara isso deve ser porque o `state.cnpj` está vazio. Acontece que no retorno você está definido o `state.cnpj` no retorno da `Promise`, que executa de forma assíncrona e quando você utiliza no `child()` ele ainda não está definido.

Só para finalizar, o que você deve fazer é colocar o trecho que busca o nó dentro do `then()`.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado.